# Is there a way to format input in python?

Tags: python-3.x, input, user-input

During the output in python the cursor automatically moves to the next line after pressing the Enter key.
Taking the below program,

```
n = input()
cost = float(input())
qty = int(input())
```

The output would be:

```
product name
12.5
2
```

But I want the output this way, with a tab intend instead.

```
product name            12.5        2
```

Is there a way to format python input in this way?

**Edit: I don't want to format the output using print, I wan't the cursor to move by tab spaces at the time of entering data itself, i.e. during input.**

Comment: Share your current code, what are you doing

Comment: this is a lot more headache than it's worth. my suggestion is to use prompts instead with your input statements: `n = input("Enter product name here")` and `cost = float(input("Enter cost of product"))` and so on. This way, you still keep clarity on what the user is entering, without having to mess with the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use print function like this

```
print('Something to print', end='\t')
```

or just use something like this

```
print(f'product name\t\t {value1}\t {value2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use

```py
print(n, cost, qty, end="\t")
```